# DateFormat: to create a new instance or to call a subclass getInstance() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, date-format

What is the correct way to use a `DateFormat` subclass? To explicitly instantiate it or to use one of the static methods of its defining class?

Moreover, in the SimpleDateFormat documentation, about synchronization, it states:

> *Synchronization*
>
> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended
>   to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple
>   threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized
>   externally.

So, what's the best approach in single-threaded applications? And in multi-threaded ones? A new instance for each thread, or a common one whose access is synchronized?
In the latter I guess that it would be better to share the pattern and create new instances when needed, but I'd like your suggestions.

Comment: Surely it depends on what the use-case is.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Either when I need a single instance in a method or when I want to share a pattern (so a date formatter) across methods. From the javadocs I can't get if it is always better to use the factory methods or not. That's what confuses me.

Comment: You can't explicitly instantiate it; it's an abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb:

- Single thread: you can reuse your DateFormat instance
- Mutithread enviroment: create a new instance each time you use it

Comment: Good. So you do not suggest to use the *DateFormat subclasses get*Instance() methods in any situation?

Comment: If you want to use the system defaults, yes. If you want to explicit format declaration, use the constructor